# How do I add new item to a multiple select field in Airtable?

Tags: airtable

Is there an easy way to add new options to the multiple select field in Airtables? Right now when I create a new record with new Multiple Select field entries I get the error

`{
  error: 'INVALID_MULTIPLE_CHOICE_OPTIONS',
  message: 'Unknown choice values: Agency',
  statusCode: 422 }`

`base('Clients').create({
    Name: 'Test',
    Tag: ['Agency']
  }`

Comment: https://community.airtable.com/t/metadata-api-for-schema-and-mutating-tables/1856/2

Comment: Having the same issue